# Como validar caracteres especiales en un campo de texto

Tags: javascript

El problema que tengo es que necesito validar un campo de texto para que solo me acepte `";"` y `"_"`. hasta el momento no me funciona con el código que tengo.

Código:

```
 function doNotSubmitFormOnEnterPress(event) {
    if (event.keyCode === 188 ) {
           return false;
    }
    return true;
 }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Puede realizar esto con *Jquery* , Puede validar si está presionado la tecla *Shift* , con la propiedad [shiftKey](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/shiftKey) , retornará un valor *booleno* si está presionada la tecla o no

```js
$('#valor').keydown(function(e) {
   if(e.shiftKey && e.keyCode ===188|| e.shiftKey && e.keyCode ===189)
     return true;
   if (e.key.length == 1) 
        return false
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text"  id="valor" >
```

Comment: +1 - Sin embargo recomiendo `if (e.key.length == 1) { return false }` en lugar de solo `return false`, de esta forma no desactiva teclas de **CTRL** tal como `Backspace` o `Delete`, Saludos!! ;)...

Comment: @fwBasic buena observación ,  gracias.

Comment: CHICOS!!!! por cierto al parer hay un tipo de error al momento de pulsar las teclas pero por lo que veo la tecla "," tiene el numero 44 y no 188 como sale en internet, estaba pensando si colocar en meta un listado de las teclas actualizado porque en mi pc la tecla 44 es la "," y la 188 no existe

Comment: Utiliza [event.key](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key) en lugar de event.keyCode, revisa el ejemplo que te deje.

Answer (score 2):

Sugiero utilizar `keypress` en lugar de `keyDown` así no limita el accionamiento de las teclas de **ctrl**, tales como: `Backspace`, `Delete`, Etc. Aunque me inclino por el uso de [jQuery](http://jquery.com) también, muestro en su lugar y para efectos ilustrativos el uso de [addEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) para manejar el evento `onKeyPress` asociado al `<input>`, asi como el uso de [event.preventDefault()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault), para prevenir el flujo normal del `<input>` en caso de no tipear los valores requeridos.

Ejemplo:

```js
document.getElementById("name").addEventListener("keypress", doNotSubmitFormOnEnterPress);

function doNotSubmitFormOnEnterPress(event) {
 if(";_".indexOf(event.key) == -1){ // colocar la cadena de caracteres permitidos
  event.preventDefault();
 };
};
```

```html
<input id="name">
```